# Word: Delete any first paragraph after the style 'Heading 2'

Tags: vba, ms-word, apache-poi

Knowing many programming languages, I don't have experience with changing very large Word files. **Please help. The would be of tremendous help!**

Can I do this by macro, VBA or Apache.POI? My first try is VBA (psuedo code), see below.

Requirement 1: How can I delete the first paragraph directly after a 'heading 2' style?

Requirement 2: The paragraph to be deleted should start with a number.

Requirement 3: The paragraph should contain italics text. And have style 'normal' or standard.

Should this be something like (pseudo code):

```
Sub DeleteParagraphAfterHeading2StaringWithNumberBeingItalics()
    heading2Found = False
    Dim para As Paragraph
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If para.Style = wdStyleHeading2
           heading2Found = True
        ElseIf heading2Found = True Then            
            txt = para.Range.Text
            If ( para.Style = wdStyleNormaltext ) And  _
               ( txt.startsWith( number) ) And  _
               ( para.Range.Font.Italic = True) Then
                para.Range.Delete
            End If
            heading2Found = False
       Else 
            heading2Found = False
       End if
       Next para
End Sub
```

Doing this by hand would take many days. So, if you can help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Style = wdStyleHeading2
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    With .Paragraphs.Last.Next.Range.Paragraphs.First.Range
      If .Style = wdStyleNormal Then
        If .Font.Italic = True Then
          If IsNumeric(Trim(.Words.First)) Then .Delete
        End If
      End If
    End With
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool code! However, the line `If .Style = wdStyleNormal Then` didn't work for me. The `.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal)` works, because `.Style` returns the style name as a string not enum

Answer (score 1):

I think the code could be like this (requires debugging on real text with real localized styles):

```
Sub del_para()
    With ActiveDocument.Range
        .Find.ClearFormatting
        .Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")    ' adjust style name
        Do
            If .Find.Execute Then   'find by style
                .Move Unit:=wdParagraph
                .Expand Unit:=wdParagraph
                If (.ListFormat.ListType = wdListOutlineNumbering _
                    Or .ListFormat.ListType = wdListSimpleNumbering _
                    Or Left(.Text, 1) Like "[0-9]") _
                    And .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("normal") _
                    And .Font.Italic Then
                    .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed    ' for debug
                    '.Delete
                End If
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You do realize that there is an enum for the built-in styles? In fact the OP used one in the question.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt in my opinion, it's usually easier to put the cursor on a paragraph, press `Ctrl+Shift+s` and copy the desired style name for the script than to pick up a number, especially considering the possible modifications of styles and the one-time use of the script. However, in terms of code cleanliness, you're absolutely right.

Comment: It’s not just for code cleanliness. The names of the built-in styles are localized. Using the enum enables your code to work regardless of language.

Comment: Thank you, looks as a good starting point! V+1.